# Once i use selfdestruct(owner) then `Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address is not a contract address`

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

How do I fix this? I've already tried `truffle migrate --reset` and/or deleting the .json files.

Comment: The error message implies that you are sending this transaction to the wrong address. It would help if you shared more code about how you are making this transaction , and how you are specifying that you are calling the right contract address.

Comment: Here is a link to the code http://github.com/devt3000/token_sale

Comment: Where is the `selfdestruct` function in your smart contract?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to delete the build output folder

Comment: /contracts/DappTokenSale.sol

Comment: I searched `DappTokenSale.sol` for `selfdestruct` and see nothing. What line...? You need to implement a function that has selfdestruct in it. You cannot just call it from the truffle console on a contract. You should also make sure that only the contract owner can call that function. Take a look [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html?highlight=selfdestruct#function-modifiers).

Comment: Use the End_Token_Sell branch. It's in the endSale function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a message from truffle framework saying that you are trying to call a function from an address which is not a contract. This is no a solidity error message.

Since you are writing about calling selfdestruct function on your contract I can only assume that you have killed your contract and then tried to call its function using truffle framework.. For example during test.

So the scenario is that you kill your contract and then try to call some of it's function. Then you will get such an error message.